# Tensorflow throws “TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'” error in Object detection session run

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, inference-engine

```
input_tensors=["import/image_tensor:0"],
output_tensors=['import/detection_boxes:0', 'import/detection_scores:0',
                        'import/detection_classes:0', 'import/num_detections:0']

_input = [graph.get_tensor_by_name(tensor_name) for tensor_name in input_tensors]
_output_ops = [graph.get_tensor_by_name(tensor_name) for tensor_name in output_tensors]
sess = tf.Session(graph=graph, config=_config_proto)

image_expanded = np array of size specific to model (1, 512, 512, 1)

(boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(self._output_ops, feed_dict={_input: image_expanded})
```

When I run the sess.run I got the error

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 3     image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
> 4     image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
> ----> 5     (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(_output_ops, feed_dict={_input: image_np_expanded})
> 6     print(boxes)
> 7     break
>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 0):

In this situation the _input is a list. So the sess.run should have _input[0]

```
(boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(self._output_ops, feed_dict={_input[0]: image_expanded})
```